# How to search for a library file on solaris?

Tags: solaris, telnet

I want to use openssl library files in a program. Openssl is installed on the server but I don't know by what name. How do I search for it on the server using telnet and include those files in my program to run it successfully?

Comment: I really don't think "telnet" has anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL consists of several library files. You may need `-lssl` or `-lcrypto` or others. Ask your system administrator where it is installed, if it's not in the default locations.

Comment: I found the header files on the server at /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl. Now the program that I have to execute needs 2 header files des.s and rand.h 
When I execute the file I get large number of errors in the included header files
Hw do I get rid of them. What is the problem?
These are the few errors that I have got:
des.h:90: error: syntax error before "DES_LONG"
des.h:90: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
des.h:90: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
des.h:91: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
des.h:92: error: syntax error before '}' token

Comment: I'm not certain. You may need to include some other openssl header before including the ones you need.